# Problem with C program to find Sudoko square 3x3 if exist in Matrix RXC

Tags: c, matrix, sudoku

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define R 4
#define C 5

// functions for option 1 initializeCountArray and TestCount and Sudoku
void initializeCountArray(int *count)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        count[i] = 0;
}

int TestCount(int *count)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        if ( count[i] == 1)
            count[0]++;
    return 1;
}

int Sudoku(int mat[R][C])
{
    int count[10] = { 0 };
    int rows,cols,i,j;

    for(rows=0; rows<R-2; rows++)
    {
        for (cols = 0; cols<C-2; cols++)
        {
            initializeCountArray(count);
            for (i = rows; i <= rows+2; i++)
            {
                for (j = cols; j <= cols+2; j++)
                {
                    count[ mat[i][j] ] ++;
                    printf("\n%d,%d",i,j);
                }
            }

            printf("\n TestCount=%d",TestCount(count));
            if (TestCount(count) == 9)
                return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void main ()
{
    int mat[R][C] = {{1,7,8,9,6},
                     {1,3,3,4,6},
                     {1,1,1,2,5},
                     {1,6,7,8,9}};

    printf ("\n Check Matrix if Suduku 3X3 square found");
    if (Sudoku(mat) == 1)
        printf("\n Sudoku square matrix was found\n");
    else
        printf("\n Sudoku square matrix NOT found\n");

}
```

---

This program should solve a specific code test that we got in class with the functions that included
and we can not use other methods when running the program the TestCount function give wrong number as output I used test printouts of indexes and I can not figure what is wrong please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:

In your `TestCount` function you use your `count[0]` as a counter for the numbers that appear in the 3x3 submatrix. I guess you wanted to do:

```
return count[0];
```

instead of your:

```
return 1;
```

Second, you do this:

```
printf("\n TestCount=%d", TestCount(count));
if (TestCount(count) == 9)
    return 1;
```

But notice your `TestCount` has some side effects. First time you call it, `count[0]` would get 9 for a Sudoku-styled 3x3 matrix, but the second time you continue incrementing `count[0]`, so it would get 18 and fail the `== 9` check - Eventually your `Sudoku` function misses it.

You should probably either set `count[0] = 0;` between calls of `TestCount()`, reset `count[0]` to 0 before you start counting in `TestCount()` or anything else you could think of (just make sure you don't overwrite it).